# Python submit and display on one click

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm new to app engine. With python.
My question is: I want to submit and display same record on add button click. As I'm using lightbox to display my records.

My html file: where add button is there.

```
<td><a href='/display?patients_id={{patient_display.key.id}}&key={{patient_display.key}}' class='display' ><input type="submit"  name="submitButtonName" value="Add" id="submitButtonName"></a></td>
```

My main.py file:

```
class DisplayAddHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("worksss")

        data_key_display = self.request.get('patients_id')
        key = self.request.get('key')
        patient_print_display = PatientInfo.get_by_id(int(data_key_display),parent=None)
        results_print_display = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM PatientMeds WHERE patientinfo_ID=" + data_key_display)
        results_patientalerts_print_display = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM PatientAlerts WHERE patientinfo_ID=" + data_key_display)

        template_values = {
        'patient_display': patient_print_display,
        'meds_display': results_print_display,
        'alert_display': results_patientalerts_print_display,

        }

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'display.html')        
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Now I want when I save record. It will saved successfully and after saving it will display the record which I have added on one click. (I mean on submit button it will save record + display).

Comment: I guess there's a bit of confusion starting from a submit button wrapped in a anchor, I'll give you a generic answer below

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you're using Google App Engine, just process form data , insert in db then [redirect](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/redirects.html) to your `showRecord` page getting id from last row id from cursor

Comment: Question edited and google-app-engine tag added later, I'm not drunk ^^

Comment: i want to display my saved record on add button click.. also.. m using lightbox for displaying the records.

Comment: Where does lightbox change things?

Comment: im using something like this for displaying <td><a href='/display?patients_id={{patient_display.key.id}}&key={{patient_display.key}}' class='display' ><input type="submit"  name="submitButtonName" value="Add" id="submitButtonName"></a></td>

Comment: I read your code in the question (and also commented), my last question is still valid.

Comment: actually lightbox is not display the saved data.. i dnt understand exactly. but i want afer saving the record it will show the record in lighbox.

Answer (score 0):

You should divide the page in to two parts. One containing the form and the other to display the records. Use ajax to submit to the datastore and then in ajax's success() function, refresh the div containing records to display the last added record.